# Boot Ubuntu server without graphic card

Tags: boot, 16.04, server, graphics

I have a computer which is running Ubuntu 16.04 x64.
The computer has only a dedicated video card which I want to remove due to power saving now.

The problem is that the server won't boot without a graphics card...

I already changed

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
```

but it didn't help anything...

How can I make the server boot without a graphic card?

Comment: Did you run `sudo update-grub`  after that change?

Comment: Yes of course...^^

Comment: Also tried what is suggested here: https://leo.steamr.com/2011/08/booting-linux-without-a-graphics-card/ --> 

Added `serial --unit=0 --speed=9600 --parity=no --stop=1
terminal --timeout=2 serial` to `/boot/grub/menu.lst`.

But it didnt help neither...

Comment: You might find [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/501307/225694) from @bodhi.zazen useful.

Comment: I guess removing the card and then installing a fresh ubuntu over ssh will be my best shot...

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 does not respond to the usual Ubuntu trusty `text` config line...

Comment: @George any workaround?

Comment: They made some changes that I still don't get but look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1088054/how-to-boot-to-command-line-interface-in-ubuntu-16-04) its talks about disabling the display manager

Comment: Another sugests adding `text`, then `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target` to achieve this I will test this now...

Comment: `sudo systemctl disable display-manager.service` gives me "No such file or directory" and what you mentioned in the comment above doesn't work either :(

Comment: Just got it to work with the following steps: 1) change the lines in `/etc/default/grub` to : `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text"`, then `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target`

Comment: I've been trying to get this same thing to work. I tried all of the items here, but had no success. Looking at the boot logs, it seems to get to `systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.` and hang until I press the power button to turn off the system.

If I put the graphics card back in the system, it boots up just fine. So strange to have a server OS that refuses to boot without a GPU.